# How to focus on certain part of an image in ImageView based on the xy-coordinates of the image?

Tags: android

i am developing an android mobile application. Currently, i have an imageview that contains a large image that are able to be drag and rotate by the users. Besides, are there anyways that i make the imageView to focus on certain part of the image based on the xy-coordinates of the image? Initially, it is focus on top-left part of the image. I want it to focus on some part based on the it coordinates.

Comment: Hi @pskink, appreciate for your time but that is not the answer that i am looking for. I want to find on how to focus on image in imageView based on its xy-coordinates instead of move/scale/rotate that image.

Comment: ok so you want to call `View#setPivotX` / `View#setPivotY` ?

Comment: Im not sure it is called pivot point of not. Basically that image is a map. I can drag the image. There is an current location button which will bring the user back to its current location in the image.

Comment: post your code then

Comment: I am not able to upload image. Just make it simple in words. I have an imageview of size 500 dp x 500 dp. It contains an image of size 1500 x 1500. How can i set the imageview to focus on certain part of the image based on x coordinate and y coordinate in an image? Like i want to set the view to the (100,102) of the image